Spring jpa Hibernate ManyToOne association loading EAGERLY even if FetchType.LAZY
I have a unidirectional ManyToOne relation which is declared as FetchType.lAZY , But when i query using Spring jpa  repo (query dsl) findAll() , ManyToOne is eagerly loaded even if DTO layer does not access this param at all .spring.jpa.open-in-view = false. I am using Spring boot 3.(Hibernate)
Say I have Employee entity , which has say office Address as ManyToOne relation
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column
    val id: String,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var group: UserGroup,

    /**
     * The address that employee belongs to.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var officeAddress: Address,
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
class Address {

    @Id
    @Column
    val id: String,

    //Other fields here
}

In the DTO layer , i am not accessing officeAddress at all ;
I enabled hibernate query,
I could see in the console that hibernate is
firing query to fetch officeAddress when I do the below.
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ["group"], type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
employeeRepository.findAll(Predicate)

This entity is shared by two modules , in one module ,
i need just the Id of office Address in the DTO , in another I need entire officeAddress.
Please note: Even if I dont access office Address at all , hibernate is still loading entire entity any way.
I have tried FetchType.LAZY , which did not work, the only way how it worked was if i just say
@Column
var officeAddressId: String; 

But as I said I need the Address to be loaded in certain scenarios fully and in certain scenarios I just need Id without fully loading it.
Also tried adding both address Id and Address like below:
@Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
var officeAddressId: String 

with
@ManyToOne(fetchType.LAZY)
var officeAddress: Address

This also anyways loaded the entity whether i accessed anything or not.

After so much investigation , I was able to find an answer to my question. I am using kotlin for spring boot 3 application. I had kotlin jpa plugin as well as kotlin spring plugin in build gradle file. Kotlin classes are final by default . So hibernate was not able to create proxy for LAZY loading. I was under the assumption that kotlin jpa will open the class (make class non final) , but it did not.  So I had to include kotlin all-open plugin as below
plugins {
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen")
id("org.springframework.boot")
id("io.spring.dependency-management")
kotlin("jvm")
kotlin("plugin.spring")
kotlin("plugin.jpa")
kotlin("kapt")
id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")

}
allOpen {
annotation("jakarta.persistence.Entity")
annotation("jakarta.persistence.Embeddable")
annotation("jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass")}

This is for Spring boot 3

Spring Boot 3 then, Spring 3 is VERY old.

I meant spring boot 3 , edited answer
